# Trying to access array offset on value of type null but database is not

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to read my database (SQL Server) it gets connected but when I try reading values this error shows up

[image: Trying to access array offset on value of type null]

This is my PHP code to read data

```
//Read RMS DB
if( $conCore2 === false )
        {
         echo "Could not connect to Core2 Server.\n";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }else{

    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        try {
            //get details status and file location of document using docno
            $sql = "SELECT [status] ,[FileLocation]  FROM [dbo].[tbl_Documents] where DocNo='".$_GET['id']."'";
           
            $resultset = sqlsrv_query($conCore2, $sql);
            
            if($resultset === false) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
            }
            
            $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultset, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
                
                echo "inside";
                if (isset($row['FileLocation'])){
                    echo $row['FileLocation'];
                }
                echo $row['FileLocation'];
                
                echo $row['status'];
```

I tried to echo the document number and it shows when I pass it using `$_GET['id']`

I also tried using isset and it seems it does not have value

Here is my code when I try to show the value

```
<div class="wrapper-container-fluid container-fluid pb-5">
        
<div class="wrapper-container container p-5 bg-white rounded">

    <div class="row">
        
        <div class="col">
            <h1 class="header">Search</h1>
            <?php
            echo $_GET['id'];
            echo $status;
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] :'' ?>">
         </div>

       
     </div>
```

I tried to Echo the sql if it is correct
[image]

here is my table in the sqlserver database

[image: database data]

I am trying to access docno 202205-00011 as seen in the example although it is not null when shown in the site it throws an error

Comment: The value `202205-00011` (from the code) is different from `202205-000011` (ID in the table). Is this a typing error?

Comment: @Zhorov thanks for pointing that out. now that you mention it I literally did not see that it is missing a zero. so that is why my query does not work. seems like a problem with my barcode when I try to read it using the scanner.

Comment: An important note - always use parameters in your statements to prevent possible SQL injection attacks. Change the code to: `$sql = "SELECT [status], [FileLocation] FROM [dbo].[tbl_Documents] where DocNo = ?"; $prm = array($_GET['id']); $resultset = sqlsrv_query($conCore2, $sql, $prm);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i know sqlserver driver for php is case sensitive and you selecting `Status` field from database as `status` in php

```php
    if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
      die('no id provided');
    }

    if ($conCore2 === false) {
      echo "Could not connect to Core2 Server.\n";
      trigger_error(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true), E_USER_ERROR);
    }

      // pay attention to field's name case Status 
      $statusField = 'Status';
      $locationField = 'FileLocation';
      $docId = $_GET['id'];
      //get details status and file location of document using docno


      $sql = "SELECT [$statusField] ,[$locationField] FROM [dbo].[tbl_Documents] where DocNo = ?";
// as mentioned in comments, don't you ever, EVER pass unprepared
// params to sql query
      $params = [$docId];
      $resultset = sqlsrv_query($conCore2, $sql, $params);

      if ($resultset === false) {
        trigger_error(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true), E_USER_ERROR);
      }

      $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultset, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

      if (!$row) {
        die('no row of empty column list');
      }

      echo "inside";      
      echo $row[$locationField];
      echo $row[$statusField];
```

Comment: don't you ever, EVER pass system error messages to the site visitor